# Groovy - need to make a printable form

Tags: xml, printing, groovy, pdf-generation, ms-office

Probably need title help as I mean a literal paper form, not an HTML element.  I have this PDF form I email everyone after they use my site, and I have to manually enter a couple fields the database knows.  I am looking for a good method to have Groovy make a pdf or something like that.

What I am going to attempt:  Make the form in Word, save as XML, put XML as groovy String and ${someVariable} everywhere I need filled in.  Open XML in Word and then print as PDF.

Is there a better way?  I have Acrobat, but if there is a way without it that's even better.

I am running into a problem which I will ask as a separate question, so get ready for a link hereish.  UPDATE: [Groovy says my Unicode string is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835798/groovy-says-my-unicode-string-is-too-long)

iText is not an option until they get back to me Re: licensing which also excludes the plugin Jared mentions (it is based on iText).

Apache thing seems to be about as hard to learn as making my rube goldberg...

Comment: Does your output have to be in PDF form?  Because that is a _lot_ of work to create an emailed form.

Comment: It can be whatever.  I just want a paper form that looks somewhat reasonable that I don't have to type in.

Comment: [iText](http://itextpdf.com) might be a good starting point...

Comment: It sounds like you've invented a Rube Goldberg machine for emailing a from. Wouldn't it be a lot simpler to just email a PDF created with iText, or a Word doc created with Apache POI, or simplest of all, a URL to a page on your site.

Comment: Maybe Jasper Reports is a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this but take a look at the [PDF Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/pdf) It looks like you can create a standard grails view containing the info you want and generate a PDF from it. I wish I had used this for my PDF generation needs.

Comment: That plugin [applies AGPL to your grails app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852278/grails-is-install-plugin-legally-safe-or-can-my-app-come-under-agpl) which is a non-trivial consideration.

Comment: But that link you wrote now recommends the rendering plugin as well.