# groovy String too long. The given string is x Unicode code units long, but only a maximum of 65535 is allowed

Tags: string, groovy, large-data

I've got a pretty simple issue:

Initializing the variable below causes a compilation error with the following error message

> "String too long. The given string is 67345 Unicode code units long,
>   but only a maximum of 65535 is allowed."

```
def tooLargeString = '{"GLOBAL_PERF":[{"name":"ALOS_Login", "baselineDays":[[93280.8, 94741.9, 97125.5, 97408.4, 100993.9, 97730.3, 97099.1], [93222.0, 93391.8, 94716.7, 97369.1, 99379.6, 97307.0, 97346.1], [93851.4, 93871.6, 92630.9, 97185.6, 98974.5, 98430.1, 96912.7], [94263.5, 92862.8, 92567.7, 97015.0, 98540.5, 97869.6, 97256.2], [93386.5, 92545.9, 92484.8, 96589.6, 99146.6, 97238.1, 96544.9], [92980.3, 92584.5, 91883.8, 97227.9, 98361.0, 97137.1, 96360.5], [93628.4, 92937.2, 92444.5, 97543.0, 99683.6, 97436.3, 95943.3], [93795.1, 92961.8, 92528.3, 96820.6, 99207.1, 97154.2, 96830.8], [93814.6, 92797.9, 92211.2, 97218.7, 99487.0, 96896.0, 96206.4], [95168.4, 93439.7, 96504.6, 98899.0, 99458.4, 97100.6, 96738.8], [95753.3, 95284.5, 97641.3, 98817.2, 101607.7, 97491.4, 95684.8], [95534.5, 95325.3, 97252.0, 100793.7, 98332.7, 97334.8, 95023.6], [95215.4, 94777.7, 97245.3, 99282.8, 98867.8, 98395.5, 95358.9], [95404.0, 94792.8, 97651.3, 99336.5, 97989.9, 98077.0, 95174.0], [96594.4, 95023.1, 99065.5, 99490.0, 98524.3, 97397.0, 95786.5], [95511.3, 94407.0, 98463.3, 99869.4, 98156.8, 97080.0, 95426.1], [95852.4, 94960.3, 98697.5, 99857.7, 99042.5, 96939.1, 95272.0], [96609.6, 94914.0, 97234.8, 100705.1, 98959.5, 97722.1, 95321.5], [96577.3, 95266.8, 97563.6, 102401.3, 98387.0, 96734.7, 95771.2], [96368.6, 96217.3, 97477.0, 101024.0, 97923.2, 96901.0, 95124.3], [94787.8, 97512.9, 97958.4, 100494.3, 98060.1, 96489.5, 94785.9], [93828.8, 100014.7, 99883.2, 103011.7, 98500.6, 97764.8, 94732.8], [94066.4, 97185.8, 98133.5, 101204.6, 97891.1, 96835.8, 94080.7], [94718.8, 96243.6, 97350.4, 100178.7, 98308.2, 97794.0, 94972.0]]},{"name":"ALS_ProxyTest", "baselineDays":[[655.9, 946.3, 699.8, 622.7, 645.2, 550.1, 549.0], [670.5, 692.6, 724.3, 653.3, 630.0, 583.1, 560.3], [641.5, 682.7, 864.1, 644.4, 577.0, 566.9, 550.9], [667.3, 745.6, 753.5, 643.2, 588.8, 578.9, 558.0], [687.9, 712.6, 738.3, 631.4, 656.0, 560.8, 557.0], [660.4, 722.3, 853.9, 636.0, 639.1, 610.5, 558.0], [683.3, 837.4, 792.0, 616.8, 639.7, 570.1, 581.9], [701.4, 782.8, 988.4, 611.0, 633.2, 561.0, 546.5], [691.8, 718.6, 752.4, 633.7, 632.3, 562.0, 578.0], [691.0, 865.9, 1606.9, 672.6, 667.9, 561.9, 567.0], [694.5, 813.3, 690.3, 665.5, 673.5, 566.8, 553.3], [701.5, 741.3, 832.9, 777.6, 802.9, 532.6, 559.5], [672.4, 891.3, 673.4, 646.8, 718.0, 575.3, 575.1], [954.8, 840.2, 732.3, 877.7, 666.2, 591.8, 573.5], [892.4, 793.9, 757.2, 687.8, 691.9, 586.5, 563.5], [994.0, 837.0, 815.2, 793.3, 716.3, 560.1, 551.4], [898.6, 834.2, 773.3, 692.0, 715.0, 562.0, 567.7], [1014.6, 1107.0, 684.2, 684.5, 739.6, 590.3, 546.6], [713.8, 816.9, 669.5, 1771.1, 563.9, 648.4, 567.3], [807.9, 706.3, 806.2, 643.8, 641.5, 1149.6, 574.4], [730.9, 1179.2, 733.9, 669.6, 608.4, 654.6, 564.7], [995.3, 2549.3, 929.8, 862.8, 579.9, 571.1, 612.5], [943.4, 1874.4, 702.1, 688.0, 579.6, 840.9, 564.4], [722.9, 682.7, 668.0, 619.2, 563.3, 567.6, 581.3]]},{"name":"Homes_LogingBE", "baselineDays":[[21244.8, 26398.2, 31389.3, 13543.5, 13811.0, 14034.7, 14131.8], [22492.1, 26249.7, 31276.9, 13834.9, 14213.3, 13760.4, 13486.5], [23634.4, 27846.2, 33580.0, 13737.1, 14137.9, 13910.5, 13592.0], [21846.6, 26669.2, 30777.8, 13628.8, 13854.4, 13702.5, 13586.4], [21962.6, 26423.8, 31396.9, 13440.0, 13893.1, 13776.4, 13787.5], [21546.3, 25818.3, 32862.1, 13264.9, 13697.9, 14025.4, 13704.2], [22147.8, 25311.5, 34814.3, 13520.6, 13488.1, 13467.0, 13584.3], [21404.2, 30001.4, 34246.3, 13492.7, 13623.9, 13464.4, 13568.6], [21486.8, 28396.8, 33426.7, 13666.0, 13740.7, 13549.8, 13651.0], [23005.2, 30783.9, 18951.3, 13744.6, 13935.7, 13823.5, 13526.3], [21108.6, 30422.6, 14003.3, 13520.3, 13389.2, 13814.6, 13639.0], [22985.8, 29195.7, 13761.0, 13603.7, 13975.0, 14209.3, 13826.3], [22479.7, 28259.2, 13919.9, 13940.5, 13899.1, 13983.2, 13610.5], [22196.2, 29774.1, 13825.4, 14230.7, 13670.8, 13782.5, 13722.2], [24462.9, 29805.8, 14138.0, 13896.7, 13669.1, 13647.3, 13644.8], [22672.2, 30084.7, 13786.5, 13619.0, 13491.7, 13588.7, 13770.3], [23509.2, 32498.5, 13899.0, 13698.6, 14000.0, 13877.3, 13438.6], [23760.5, 31145.2, 13945.2, 13774.3, 13954.9, 14034.8, 13821.8], [21812.7, 31364.0, 14060.6, 14357.7, 13641.3, 13968.4, 13725.8], [24734.6, 28532.0, 13627.1, 13896.1, 13500.3, 13978.2, 13920.2], [23978.8, 32638.4, 14249.4, 14258.7, 13621.3, 13733.7, 14025.6], [26078.2, 30315.0, 14172.2, 13750.3, 13715.5, 15034.9, 13639.0], [25697.2, 31795.7, 13140.8, 13948.5, 13917.0, 13906.8, 13847.7], [24817.3, 31644.8, 13448.8, 13855.3, 13949.5, 13351.1, 13710.9]]},...{"name":"Scada_SWORDAS", "baselineDays":[[16368.8, 16945.5, 21055.0, 15001.9, 14998.8, 14302.4, 14862.2], [18952.7, 18338.1, 19326.3, 16850.4, 15422.6, 14491.1, 15465.5], [18775.5, 18456.0, 21693.7, 28809.9, 15131.9, 15628.4, 14680.0], [17718.1, 18722.3, 19907.8, 24651.7, 15931.3, 14432.0, 14622.3], [18184.6, 17556.5, 21642.0, 17500.2, 15458.8, 14535.2, 14210.0], [18725.5, 18799.9, 22388.5, 17080.3, 15404.5, 14172.3, 14066.2], [18214.1, 17573.5, 22124.8, 18082.2, 14771.6, 14127.0, 14109.2], [19043.5, 19999.2, 22768.0, 18249.7, 15472.9, 14460.0, 14544.5], [18772.9, 20561.4, 21675.8, 15417.0, 15974.4, 14438.3, 13456.6], [23104.8, 24288.2, 19904.4, 15783.4, 15180.0, 15040.5, 14608.3], [18507.8, 20486.2, 15135.2, 16404.0, 15084.8, 14557.2, 14285.7], [19961.3, 20651.0, 14943.0, 15135.4, 14925.5, 14449.5, 14183.9], [17966.8, 19517.8, 15183.0, 14812.2, 14577.3, 14492.5, 14015.0], [18166.6, 21157.7, 14693.5, 16337.2, 14270.6, 14930.2, 14427.5], [19154.9, 18565.7, 15318.5, 14914.6, 14542.3, 15221.4, 15007.4], [22086.7, 24164.6, 18619.5, 17037.0, 14486.4, 14439.7, 15035.0], [23285.1, 25943.9, 20656.2, 18960.6, 15100.8, 14486.0, 15210.0], [21571.0, 22192.4, 16442.8, 16084.2, 14446.6, 14067.9, 15454.2], [20494.0, 18674.8, 15177.5, 15287.5, 13804.6, 14502.4, 14296.8], [19094.9, 19349.3, 15633.3, 14849.0, 14537.7, 14775.2, 14687.5], [19856.2, 20010.4, 16157.0, 13998.1, 15622.7, 15073.3, 14845.5], [18296.5, 18679.9, 14662.5, 15596.6, 14354.2, 14793.0, 14322.6], [20261.4, 20092.6, 14943.9, 16516.0, 14428.1, 15086.3, 14033.0], [19257.1, 18178.0, 15468.4, 15851.5, 14175.6, 14821.5, 15025.0]]},{"name":"Scada_SWORDEU", "baselineDays":[[7128.8, 10512.0, 14019.8, 3935.9, 4593.3, 4138.5, 4517.0], [8003.6, 7938.1, 12911.9, 4415.8, 4161.2, 4170.4, 4221.6], [8530.2, 9516.3, 13062.8, 4081.4, 4061.6, 5070.8, 4476.9], [8565.0, 10152.2, 11803.1, 4053.3, 4158.5, 4243.4, 4668.5], [8254.9, 7864.0, 12834.7, 4084.6, 4056.5, 4167.8, 4777.7], [9253.3, 9157.8, 13834.5, 4129.4, 4066.4, 5101.5, 4140.2], [7466.4, 8046.8, 14430.7, 4017.2, 4071.4, 4127.8, 4119.6], [7613.7, 11320.6, 15650.5, 3979.7, 4363.8, 4034.8, 5113.4], [8121.3, 9085.4, 14041.3, 4294.0, 4291.3, 4022.0, 4962.4], [6931.0, 10507.2, 5873.1, 4133.0, 4208.0, 4087.4, 4942.5], [8063.8, 9542.1, 4095.7, 4093.1, 4859.2, 4083.4, 4160.7], [7970.0, 9523.3, 4139.9, 4299.5, 4079.8, 4215.3, 5010.8], [8514.4, 8689.4, 4473.0, 4309.8, 4247.4, 3999.3, 4079.3], [9819.5, 9929.5, 4019.5, 4552.2, 4148.7, 3987.5, 4098.5], [8863.0, 9436.0, 3938.8, 4074.8, 4975.4, 4075.5, 4297.8], [8279.8, 11751.5, 3905.2, 4077.0, 4184.0, 4874.9, 4332.3], [8129.4, 10037.2, 3975.9, 5397.7, 4253.1, 5249.5, 4092.9], [11608.2, 13561.8, 4094.5, 4101.9, 4238.2, 4237.9, 4064.6], [8599.3, 11339.1, 4151.3, 5142.4, 4470.9, 4157.3, 4132.3], [9218.4, 11990.8, 4983.4, 4458.6, 4111.0, 5278.0, 4194.9], [8939.5, 14791.0, 4537.2, 5199.8, 4316.8, 5117.4, 4145.9], [9443.0, 9211.2, 5569.6, 4373.4, 4156.6, 5147.2, 4182.8], [10185.4, 13006.2, 4069.5, 4206.3, 4532.7, 4638.8, 4956.4], [9109.5, 12312.3, 4278.7, 4359.8, 4066.7, 4070.1, 4256.0]]}]}'
```

Does someone know a workaround? Since I'd like to later compare this whole string with  a regexp.

something like

```
if (str ==~ /^\{\"[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\"\:\[(\{\"name\"\:\"[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\"\,\s?\"baselineDays\"\:\[[\[([0-9]+[\.[0-9]+]?\,?\s?)+\]\,?\s?]+\]\}\,?\s?)+\]\}/) {
    println "match" 
} else {
    println "not match" 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, format this question appropriately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Groovy says my Unicode string is too long](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835798/groovy-says-my-unicode-string-is-too-long)

Comment: Problem solved. I've found the solution to this issue. I split my original string to a substring of chunk of 64K, then use stringBuffer.append to  reconstruct the string. And it works!

Comment: @viz optionally you can load your string from file using `def str = new File("/path/yourfile.txt").text`